# malloc with C struct in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, malloc

I am trying to write some tests in Catch2 (a C++ library) for a simple C library example and I am a little confused about how to initialize a C struct.

My C header looks like this:

```cpp
struct node;
```

And my C implementation cannot be simpler:

```cpp
struct node {
  int num;
  struct node* next;
}
```

Now, the problem is with the test (in C++):

```cpp
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
extern "C" {
  #include "node.h"
}

TEST_CASE("would it work?", "[foo]") {
  struct node* n = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

The code will not compile because "`struct node` is an incomplete type".

My question, in cases like this, how do you initialize C structs like that one in C++ code? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're taking the `sizeof(struct node)`, but you haven't told the compiler what's in `struct node`. In other words, the structure definition in the C implementation needs to be visible in the C++ file. That's *if* you want to allocate memory for the struct in the C++ file.

Comment: In a case like that, you need to call whatever function the C API exposes to create the `node` structures. If there isn't any such function then perhaps the design or the implementation needs to be looked over? And in almost *all* cases you should never use `malloc` in C++, even for "C" structures. Generally, whenever you need to do a C-style cast then you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If this is your real code then you forgot a semicolon after the struct definition.

Comment: You probably should put `struct node { int num;  struct node* next;}` in the C header "node.h" instead the C implementation.

Comment: Even in a using C application you will have the same problem when you try to allocate a structure. Please show us more of the header file, or correct.

Comment: The alternative to exposing `struct node` in the .h is to expose a pair of functions `malloc_node` and `free_node`.

Comment: To calculate `sizeof` for your `struct` type, both C and C++ compilers need visibility of the complete definition of the type (i.e. your "C implementation") not just a declaration (your "C header").    This means, in your case, that the code which calls `malloc()` (whether compiled as C or C++) needs visibility of the `struct` definition.

Comment: What C++ code? I can see none

Comment: @tstanisl The test uses *Catch2* framework, which is written in C++, although it can also be used to test C and Objective-C code bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically everything has already been said in the comments.

You are just forward declaring the struct in the header. While it is best practice to use forward declarations to reduce include dependencies in headers that just need to know what something is (e.g. a struct) but not what it contains, it usually doesn't make much sense to forward declare the struct in the header that is actually supposed to define the struct itself.

Using a struct (including `malloc`) beyond just needing to know that it is a pointer or a reference requires knowledge of the definition of that struct. Note that your C++ file only sees the contents of the included header; it doesn't see the contents of the C file. Therefore, the forward declaration in the header should replaced by the struct definition from the C file, making the C file obsolete in case it was really only intended to define the struct.